# Iterate webpages through selenium python to get position of search result

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am searching a generic keyword and finding my products rank on an an e-commerce site. Here is my code for that which works successfully.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome( "C:\All\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe" )
driver.get('https://web.com/searchall?b=1&kw=printer')
items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('productResult')
for i, item in enumerate( items ):
if 'EPSON' in item.text:
print( i )
```

This only fetches rank on first page but now I want to go to every page and fetch the rank of my product. I know I have to use a loop which is somewhat like this:

```
while True: 
try: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="pageNavigation nextPage"]/a').click() 
except: 
break
```

I am finding difficulty in exact placement of the loop. Please help me with the syntax. I am a newbie.

Comment: Your for code block's indentation is wrong I believe. See http://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php. If you want the if statement to be executed for every iteration of the for command, you need to indent it. If you need your print statement to be executed within the if block, you need to add an extra indent to it.

Comment: I did.. but I am not understanding exact way.. Can you please help me with the syntax

Comment: We could try another example: http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome( "C:\All\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe" )
driver.get('https://shop.techdata.com/searchall?b=1&kw=printer')

items_count = 0

while True: 
    items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('productResult')
    for i, item in enumerate( items ):
        if 'EPSON' in item.text:
            print(items_count + i)
    items_count += len(items)
    try: 
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="pageNavigation nextPage"]/a').click()
    except:
        break
```

This should allow you to integrate your second part into first one with correct indentation

Comment: I tried doing this but it gives wrong value for the position i. It gives following values which are wrong.... 3
4
5
6
22
21
20
23
0
4
6
9
13
18
1
3
6
7
8
9
12
14
22
12
9
10
18
21
22
5
6
10
3

Comment: Why do you think that they are wrong? It seem to be correct values.

Comment: Those are the search position numbers of search results. on first page rank should be 4, 5,6,7. Each page has 25 records so, if there is an occurrence of word 'Epson' on the second page(lets say second position), the output should be 27. Hopefully you understood what I meant.

Comment: Nope. I am sorry but this is still giving wrong search result ranking

Comment: Are you sure? I got following: 3, 4, 5, 6, 97, 146, 695, 698, 700, 704, 706, 709, 713...

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Hope it will help -

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome( "C:\All\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe" )
driver.get('https://shop.techdata.com/searchall?b=1&kw=printer')

items_count = 1

while True: 
    items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('productResult')
    for i, item in enumerate( items ):
        if 'EPSON' in item.text:
            print(items_count + i)
    items_count += 25
    try: 
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="pageNavigation nextPage"]/a').click()
    except:
        break
```